# What is this distribution called?

Tags: probability

$F_i=n {m-i \choose n-1}$

where $m \ge n, 1 \le i \le m-n+1$

For instance, if $m=10, n=5$, I can draw a line graph.
[image]

Comment: In your example, $i$ should only go up to $6$?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, it should terminate at 6 in this case.

Comment: In what sense is this a "distribution"?  It just looks like a sequence to me.

Comment: @user3296 The $\sum F_i$ should be normalized to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the factor $n$, it is (reversed) a certain column in Pascal's triangle.  Your example is $5{j\choose 4}$ for $j$ from $0$ to $9$.  In your picture $j$ numbers it from right to left, while numbers it $i$ from left to right.